# AVCaptureDevice - iphone/ipad as video source

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

Can AVCaptureDevice be used (objective-c or Swift) to access an iOS device as a camera source, when it is connected via a lightning cable, very much like Quicktime does for OSX Yosemite?

[Quicktime select camera source image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5gw4jjxt8s3ggst/iphone.png?dl=0)

If not, is there any other way to capture it?

I'm using AVCaptureDevice.devices() (in swift) but it only lists the built-in Mac camera and mic.

Comment: Michael, I want to know how to do it in objective-c or swift... not a user question...

Comment: Sorry about that. I must have been zoning out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution for this (thanks [Chris Adamson](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506165932/http://subfurther.com/blog/)), after looking at [a presentation on WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2014/#508) where Apple announced this capability - fast forward to 4:09.

The following CMI property needs to be set before AVCaptureDevice can detect the iOS device as a camera/capture device (example in Swift):

```
var prop : CMIOObjectPropertyAddress = CMIOObjectPropertyAddress(
        mSelector: CMIOObjectPropertySelector(kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices),
        mScope: CMIOObjectPropertyScope(kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal),
        mElement: CMIOObjectPropertyElement(kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster))
    
var allow:UInt32 = 1
    
CMIOObjectSetPropertyData( CMIOObjectID(kCMIOObjectSystemObject),
        &prop,
        0,
        nil,
        UInt32(sizeofValue(allow)),
        &allow)
```

After this is done (e.g. in your AppDelegate), the standard registration of observers can be done, and the iOS camera will show up in the list of available devices

```
// register for notifications when a new device is connected
notifications.registerObserver(AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification, forObject: session, block: {note in
        
    var devices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeMuxed)
                +  AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) as! [AVCaptureDevice]

    for device in self.devices {
        if device.modelID == "iOS Device" {
            // device is your AVCaptureDevice... use it as usual
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: ?? what are you questioning @AbdulYasin ??

Comment: @ Gonçalo Borrêga: My question is can i use iPhone as a source for showing live camera preview on watch. Something like i can use with HomeKit. My goal is to show camera preview on watch directly from paired iPhone device.

Comment: @AbdulYasin this is about using the iPhone as a source camera connected to a Mac (and showing what's on the iphone in the mac). To show video/images on the watch, a different approach must necessarily be followed (don't even know if AV* classes are supported on the watch framework

Comment: how to capture video file for objective c application